# Interpreting WHERE= in Proc

Tags: sas

Converting a SAS code to Sql based process. Came across this pretty simple snippet.

```
         proc freq data=temp1(where=(SAMERETAIL='Y')) noprint;
         tables RETAILER*store/list nocum nopercent out=retailer_list;
         run;
```

My interpretation of this is:

```
      From Temp1:
       Choose all observations which fit the criteria (sameretail=Y)
       Extract Retail, Store frequency counts:
                     Store       Retailer       Count(*)

       Output to Retailer_List.
```

The question I have is on the WHERE=. Is this applied to the Proc or Data? Is my interpretation correct? Business wise this is incorrect since we are only restricting the records with the flag=Y. Hence the question.
Any pointers?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`where=` is applied to the dataset you're pulling observations from to use in the `proc freq`. SUGI 24 has a good [summary](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi24/Begtutor/p59-24.pdf) of how this works (see page 3).

> THE WHERE DATA SET OPTION
>
> The syntax of the WHERE data set option, called
> WHERE=, is a combination of standard data set
> option parentheses and a where-expression.

Comment: Thank you. So this means, it filters the data using the criteria specified in Where= and the proc freq calculates the frequency distribution of it, correct?